# Space complexity of a given recursive program

Tags: c, algorithm, space-complexity

Consider the following C-function:

```
double foo (int n) {
 int i; 
 double sum; 
 if (n == 0) return 1.0; 
 else { 
        sum = 0.0; 
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            sum + = foo (i); 
        return sum; 
      }
}
```

The space complexity of the above function is

```
1)  O(1)
2)  O(n)
3)  O(n!)
4)  O(n^n)
```

in the above question, according to me, answer should be (2) but answer is given as (3) option. Although it is recursive function but stack will never have more than O(n) stack depth. Can anyone explain me why is this answer (3) and where am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @devnull : if(n == 0) return 1.0; // it is used to control the recursive function so that at some point the control is returned.
 so, yes it will compile .

Comment: Perhaps the question measures "space complexity" by total memory allocated, rather than the maximum amount of memory allocated at any one point in time. In which case, it would be more than O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You needed time complexity then it is certainly not `O(N!)` as many suggest but way less then that it is `O(2^N)`.

Proof:-

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + T(N-2) + T(N-3) + T(N-4)........T(1)
```

moreover by above formula

```
T(N-1) = T(N-2) + T(N-3)...... T(1)
```

hence `T(N) = T(N-1) + T(N-1) = 2*T(N-1)`

solving above gives `T(N) = O(2^N)`

Whereas if you needed space complexity then for recursive function space complexity is calculated by the amount of stack space at max occupied by it at a moment and that in this case cannot exceed of `O(N)`

But in any case the answer is not `O(N!)` because that many computations are not done at all so how can stack occupy that much space.

**Note:-** Try to run the function for `n = 20` if it doesnt cause memory overflow then answer given in text will be 20! which is larger than any memory but i think it will run in `O(2^20)` time without any stack overflow.

Comment: thanks. You actually clarified my doubt. And I tried the running it with input value 5 and was getting 2^n function calls each call executing O(1) time , so time complexity is O(2^n) but with dynamic programming, the complexity would reduce.

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA Yes if you use memoization then your time complexity would be reduced to O(N) but from the function i get that you are calculating 2^(N-1) which can done using bitwise shift operations in O(1)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this:

To calculate **foo(n)** . The program have to calculate: foo(0)+foo(1)+foo(2) ... foo(n-1):

Similarly for foo(n-1). The program have to recursively calculate: foo(0) + foo(1) + ... foo(n-2).

Basically you will have O(foo(n)) = n! + (n-1)! + (n-2)! + ... 1! = O(n!).

Hope this is clear.

Comment: This sounds like a good argument for the time complexity of the algorithm, but does it also apply to the space complexity?

Comment: I assume you mean `foo(n) = ...`, or `O(foo(n)) = O(...)`, because the way you wrote it there is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, like several other posts said. This is for Time Complexity only. My bad ... Also, asdukeling said my notation also wrong ...

Comment: @user2459179 : thanks for your answer but isn't it time complexity which you are talking about? i mean can you clarify it? what is your answer finally, is am i wrongly thinking the answer? because i think even if function has N! function calls that calls are occupying max n space in the stack .

Comment: @user2459179 Firstly the question is about space complexity and moreover time complexity is also O(2^N) not O(N!) .  Proof:- T(N) = T(N-1) + T(N-2) + T(N-3).....T(1) therefore T(N-1) = T(N-2) + T(N-3).... hence T(N) = 2*T(N-1) which when solved gives O(2^N)

Answer (score 1):

Space complexity is O(N). at any given time the space used is limited to: 
 `N*sizeof_function_call_which_is_a_constant`.